# Typescript dollar sign output same as code

Tags: typescript, console.log

```
for (let email of CONTACT_EMAIL_ARRAY) {
        console.log('found contact : ${email}');
        }
```

In source textbook, console output is::::: found contact: example mail 1, 2, 3 etc.

When I try it locally it just says : found contact : ${email}

Every time I use console log with a dollar sign ::: output is the same

What is missing?

Comment: You need to replace the `'` character for `\``

Comment: See [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) string interpolation. The syntax for those uses the backtick (`) character instead of a quotation mark (' or "):

```js
const CONTACT_EMAIL_ARRAY = ["Jonathan (a@b.c)", "David (b@c.d)"]

for (const email of CONTACT_EMAIL_ARRAY) {
  console.log(`found contact : ${email}`);
  // note the usage of ` instead of ' ^^^
}
```